# Show message only when using --help in python click

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am contributing to open source project which uses click for it's command line interface.

I want to show a message **only** when the `--help` flag is used

**Expected Result**

`manim --help`

```
normal cli stuff that was there before


The message I'd like to add
```

**What I've tried**

1. Using @click.option

```
@click.option(
    "--help",
    is_flag=True,
    help="For more information regarding configuration and rendering"
)
```

Output:

```
Manim Community v0.9.0

Usage: manim [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: Missing command.
```

NOTE: This is the file that I'm trying to change if it's helpful

https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/blob/main/manim/__main__.py

Comment: What command are you executing?

Comment: the exact command that will be executed is ```manim --help```